# Routing between 2 routers on home network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing

I have a home network with 2 routers,

A Main router (192.168.1.xxx), and the mesh (Tenda) router (192.168.2.xxx), which its main node is in the 192.168.1 network (192.168.1.14).

The problem is that the main router (192.168.1.1) can't find the 192.168.2 network (and I can't add static route to it).

I tried different approach, I added static routing on windows (to my machine on 192.168.1.15 which is directly connected to the main router).
I see using wireshark that the it tries to find a machine on the 192.168.2 network using the main Tenda node (192.168.1.14), but strangely, this Tenda node can't find a route.
The Tenda router (the main node is in the 192.168.1) failed to find a computer which is on the 192.168.2 network.
The other side works, I can ping from a computer on the 192.168.2 network to a computer on the 192.168.1 network.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Eli

Comment: A ping working only in one direction is often related to firewall issue. You should check the firewall configuration on the router and on the different hosts.

Comment: Good idea, i will test it

Comment: I tested the firewall suggestion. 
I turned off all the firewalls in the network.
Still the problem persists.

Eli

Comment: Could you check if there is NAT (Network Address Translation) configure on the router ?

Comment: There is no NAT configured on the router.
I see its possible to configure NAT, but the configuration only accepts a list of MAC address (it doesn't make sense to me), what will the router do with this MACS?